# SQL: Select colums from tables and compare + count

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am improving my php script which has two simple sql queries. What Im trying to do is to combine the two queries into one.

1st query:

```
SELECT categories.*, entries.* 
FROM categories, entries 
WHERE entries.cat_id = categories.cat_id 
ORDER BY dateposted ASC 
LIMIT 5;
```

2nd query:

```
SELECT comments.* 
FROM comments 
WHERE comments.entry_id = '. $row['id'].';
```

These two work great when separate. I just need to combine them into one(still simple, no UNION or INNER JOINs please) and possibly count a number of comments for a particular entry right in the query.
Also, my "comments" table has five columns (comment_id, post_id, author, body, dateposted) if this is any helpful to know.

I tried different ways. Something like this:

```
SELECT categories.*, entries.*, COUNT(comments.entry_id) AS comm_num 
FROM categories, entries, comments 
WHERE entries.cat_id = categories.cat_id 
AND comments.entry_id = entries.id 
ORDER BY dateposted ASC LIMIT 5;
```

did not work...

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need `GROUP BY` if you use aggregate functions. Also it is always a good idea to specify the column names clearly instead of using wildcard.

Comment: what is it showing now. Is it showing error or what?

Comment: The approach you're taking may seem simple to you as a coder, but it's definitely going to slow down the performance when the number of records increase in the entries and comments table. Given that one entry has many comments, you're spelling disaster in terms of performance. So you'd better get used to nested queries with suitable joins.

Comment: Working on it. GROUP BY isn't working yet. Im using it like this:  SELECT categories.*, entries.*, SUM(comments.entry_id) AS total_comments FROM categories, entries, comments GROUP BY author ....

Comment: Itsols: well, that's what Im trying to do, incease the performance of my script by combining the queries and caching them :). I might be wrong here, but I read that JOINS will slow down query time and it's better to avoid them. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Using `FROM categories, entries, comments` is the equivalent of a CROSS JOIN, and filtering them by WHERE table1.field = table2.field is the equivalent of an INNER JOIN, so you aren't really avoiding joins, just avoiding the semantic terminology...  Why do you think joins will be slow in your case?  How many rows do you anticipate in these tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query is essentially a join, and it may not be any faster.  You can query for entries (while displaying the corresponding category information) like so:

```
SELECT entries.*, categories.* 
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN categories ON entries.cat_id = categories.cat_id 
ORDER BY dateposted ASC 
LIMIT 5;
```

Also, it sounds like you don't actually want to return each comment row in this query, but rather just obtain a comment count per "entry".  For that count, you can likely do this:

```
SELECT entries.*, categories.*, COUNT(comments.comment_id) AS comm_num  
FROM entries
LEFT JOIN categories on entries.cat_id = categories.cat_id
LEFT JOIN comments on comments.entry_id = entries.entry_id
GROUP BY entries.entry_id
ORDER BY dateposted ASC 
LIMIT 5;
```

Note the COUNT function is counting comment IDs, not entry IDs.

Comment: Bjorn Nelson: Thank you! Your query worked like a charm. Very interesting.. Now Im trying to figure out how exactly it works without a WHERE clause :).